# "Bitmap too large" when changing my background DPI to 240

Tags: android, dpi

My background always look bad in my app on my smartphone, so I searched around and found [THIS](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) article, so I created 3 copies of my background (120,160,240) DPI, but now I get this error:

> 03-16 11:41:13.984: W/OpenGLRenderer(19236): Bitmap too large to be
>   uploaded into a texture (1676x2666, max=2048x2048)

Now I wonder how can I follow these instructions (provide a 240 DPI background image), and also have it reasonably sized so I dont get this error?

Comment: what is the resolution of the images in each of the folders?

Answer (score 0):

use largeHeap, it is only supported from 3.0. If your phone is earlier then Honey Comb, then can't use this. .